# Delete gap between stacked upper and lower boxes

Tags: html, css

I created a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/celiostat/zgUgn/

this is for a dynamic webpage. depending on the user, their might be 4 (as in the example) or 13 collections (on square = one collection). Height of image and collection title can vary. Consequently  boxe height varies, and on the second row, I get a gap between collection above and collection below whereas I would like to keep that space between the boxes even; say 25px.
Thanks for your help !

HTML:

```
    <div class="collection_bookmars_container">
        <img class="collection_random_image" src="http://img.foodnetwork.com/FOOD/2012/05/04/FNM-060112_NTD-Hot-Dog-Sandwich_s4x3_lg.jpg">
        <div class="collection_bookmark_title_container">
            <span class="collection_bookmark_title">Thai favorites</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modify_collection_container">
            <span class="number_of_articles">1</span>
            <span class="article_text_only">articles</span>
            <img class="icon_modify_collection" src="http://www.mricons.com/store/png/124258_43263_128_monotone_pen_write_icon.png">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collection_bookmars_container">
        <img class="collection_random_image" src="http://img.foodnetwork.com/FOOD/2013/07/19/FNM_090113-Name-This-Dish-Stacked-Salad-Recipe_s4x3_lg.jpg">
        <div class="collection_bookmark_title_container">
            <span class="collection_bookmark_title">Best France food stuff</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modify_collection_container">
            <span class="number_of_articles">1</span>
            <span class="article_text_only">articles</span>
            <img class="icon_modify_collection" src="http://www.mricons.com/store/png/124258_43263_128_monotone_pen_write_icon.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collection_bookmars_container">
        <img class="collection_random_image" src="http://img.foodnetwork.com/FOOD/2012/05/04/FNM-060112_NTD-Hot-Dog-Sandwich_s4x3_lg.jpg">
        <div class="collection_bookmark_title_container">
            <span class="collection_bookmark_title">Snacks</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modify_collection_container">
            <span class="number_of_articles">1</span>
            <span class="article_text_only">articles</span>
            <img class="icon_modify_collection" src="http://www.mricons.com/store/png/124258_43263_128_monotone_pen_write_icon.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collection_bookmars_container">
        <img class="collection_random_image" src="http://www.secondhomemalaysia.co.uk/uploads/Food3.jpg">
        <div class="collection_bookmark_title_container">
            <span class="collection_bookmark_title">Soups and veloutes</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modify_collection_container">
            <span class="number_of_articles">1</span>
            <span class="article_text_only">articles</span>
            <img class="icon_modify_collection" src="http://www.mricons.com/store/png/124258_43263_128_monotone_pen_write_icon.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    background-color: #ECF0F1;
}


.container
{
    max-width: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}


.table_presentation_two_column
{
    height: auto;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.collection_bookmars_container
{
    height: auto;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 46%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 20px 2% 0% 2%;
}

.collection_random_image
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}


.collection_bookmark_title_container
{
    margin: 30px 4% 0px 4%;
}


.collection_bookmark_title
{
    font-family: "Roboto Slab","serif";
    font-size: 30px;

}

.modify_collection_container
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin: 20px 4% 0px 4%;
    padding-top: 15px;
    border-top: 3px solid #EBEBEB;
    width: 92%;
}

.number_of_articles
{
    font-size: 16px
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    color: #AFAFAF;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.article_text_only
{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    color: #AFAFAF;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.icon_modify_collection
{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 12%;
    max-width: 250px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: -5;
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the 20px gap resulting from `.collection_bookmars_container` top margin of 20px?

Comment: @MarcAudet OP said they want a small gap. I think the OP wants it like Windows Live Tiles but with the small margins for some spacing

Comment: I think I know what's going on.  The boxes are taking the height of the lowest row.  He wants all boxes to have a consistent distance apart.
I recently ran into this problem, and used a javascript plugin called Masonry to help out.  I'd like to know if there is a css only solution.

Comment: In lieu of trying to create your own modular system, perhaps check out Twitter's bootstrap?

Comment: @Alexander thanks, I will check it out -  though ... I do not know JS at all for now

Comment: @lauWM masonry is easy to implement, they tell you all the script you need to use it on the site.  You can even just call it with HTML and just include the js file.

Comment: @paintedcones as I am new to HTML and CSS, i left bootstrap aside for now, because it added a layrer of complexity in the learning process, if you could point me to which part of the framework I could  use...that would me much appreciated !

Comment: ok Alex, will look now , just entirely new at it, so ill check first HOW to call it form HTML and where to include the file!

Comment: @lauWM bootstrap will actually make this a lot EASIER, since the infrastructure is there already. Check out the [grid section](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) of Bootstrap CSS... you'll want to use that. There's no need to reinvent the wheel... especially when the wheel has so much GOOD documentation.

Comment: @Alex, great works like a charm, almost - because when I resize the browser window, there is some overlaping among div happening

Comment: @paintedcones, yep right, I guess it was just a bit overwhelming learning html/css from scratch

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/) to do what you want, there is no other way doing it nicely because of the height difference. The wrapper is what is wrecking it for you.

Perhaps another idea is to create the wrappers for each column instead of each row.

Comment: thanks David, as mentioned above in my comment, i have no knowledge of JS at the moment ! so we look  at JS solution as soon as possible !